# jq not replacing json value with parameter

Tags: json, variables, jq, string-literals, string-interpolation

test.sh is not replacing test.json parameter values ($input1 and $input2). result.json has same ParameterValue "$input1/solution/$input2.result"

```
 [
    {
      "ParameterKey": "Project",
      "ParameterValue": [ "$input1/solution/$input2.result" ]
     }
    ]
```

### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
input1="test1"
input2="test2"
echo $input1
echo $input2
cat test.json | jq 'map(if .ParameterKey == "Project"           then . + {"ParameterValue" : "$input1/solution/$input2.result" }             else .             end           )' > result.json
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

shell variables in *jq* scripts should be interpolated or passed as arguments via `--arg name value`:

```
jq --arg inp1 "$input1" --arg inp2 "$input2" \
'map(if .ParameterKey == "Project" 
    then . + {"ParameterValue" : ($inp1 + "/solution/" + $inp2 + ".result") } 
else . end)' test.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Project",
    "ParameterValue": "test1/solution/test2.result"
  }
]
```

Comment: Don't interpolate shell values into a `jq` script; in general, you don't know fi the result will *be* a valid `jq` script.

Comment: @chepner, yes, I prefer to pass variables via `--arg name value`

Comment: If i remove the square brackets in the begining/end of the json, it is not working.                                                                                                      {
      "ParameterKey": "Project",
      "ParameterValue": [ "$input1/solution/$input2.result" ]
     }

Comment: @spiderman, if you remove  square brackets - that will be completely another input. Another input - another issue, another case, not the current one

Answer (score 3):

In your jq program, you have quoted "$input1/solution/$input2.result", and therefore it is a JSON string literal, whereas you evidently want string interpolation; you also need to distinguish between the shell variables ($input1 and $input2) on the one hand, and the corresponding jq dollar-variables (which may or may not have the same name) on the other.

Since your shell variables are strings, you could pass them in using the `--arg` command-line option (e.g. `--arg input1 "$input1"` if you chose to name the variables in the same way).

You can read up on string interpolation in the jq manual (see https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual, but note the links at the top for different versions of jq).

There are other ways to achieve the desired results too, but using string interpolation with same-named variables, you'd write:

```
"\($input1)/solution/\($input2).result"
```

Notice that the above string is NOT itself literally a JSON string. Only after string interpolation does it become so.

Comment: In jq 1.6, this doesn't seem to work. A complete example: `echo '{"hello": "Planet \($w)"}' | jq --arg w "world"`

Comment: I need it it to read the input from stdin. If I provide -n it just outputs null, as expected.

Comment: @four43 - Your input to jq is not JSON. Please reread the last para of the response above.

Comment: @four43 - Maybe you should ask a separate question on SO to cover your use-case.

Comment: \@peak yes it is, and I did :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73520524/using-jq-how-do-i-substitute-a-variable-within-a-string

Also how tf do I tag someone lol. This is silly