# Using jq, how do I substitute a variable within a string?

Tags: arguments, command-line-interface, jq

When given a string in JSON where I'd like only a part of it templated/substituted:

```
{
  "title": "Where the $color Fern Grows"
}
```

Trying to template that with `jq` args doesn't seem to work:

```
cat example.json | jq --arg color "Red"
```

`jq` doesn't like the substitution and returns the un-templated example.json with `$color` in the output

How can you tell `jq` to replace variables mid JSON string?

Thanks.

#### Solution:

The issue seems to be that `jq` assumes data on stdin is formatted JSON data. This substitution actually only works on a "filter", which is `jq`'s term for a script. Using the flags `-n` and `-f [filter.json]` to correctly state the input data is a filter, not actual data and using the `\($var)` syntax, as @peak pointed out works well.

`example.json` then could become `example.jq`:

```
{
  "title": "Where the \($color) Fern Grows"
}
```

Which when run, as they suggested:

```
jq -n --arg color "Red" -f example.jq
```

Works perfectly. The concept between data and filter is important and one I didn't realize. I thought it was all just interpolation and templating like most other programs. This seems to take more inspiration from `awk` where this is common however.

Comment: Not sure why you are replicating the answer as part of the Q, but in any case, note that the problem with your original approach is that jq expects JSON (or raw strings) on its STDIN, not a jq program.  It has nothing to do with mangling.  Perhaps you could adjust/moderate your commentary elsewhere accordingly.

Comment: Ah I see so there is a difference between a jq filter (their words) and the data. Args only work on filters

Comment: And this is precicely why I restated your answer - to elaborate and make sure I understood it fully (which apparently I didnt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For suggested ways to use jq as a template engine, see the jq Cookbook:
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#using-jq-as-a-template-engine

In your case, it would probably be better to use the "interpolation" approach as per your original SO question: [jq not replacing json value with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47374719/jq-not-replacing-json-value-with-parameter/47375032?noredirect=1#comment129830637_47375032)

##### example.jq:

```
{
  "title": "Where the \($color) Fern Grows"
}
```

##### Invocation:

```
jq -n --arg color Red -f example.jq
```

or:

```
jq --arg color Red . <(example.jq)
```

### Otherwise ...

... you could use `sub`, though that might be brittle.

Comment: Oh interesting, so it is exclusively a stdin issue? That's what you were hinting in that other question. Thanks for jumping over here and helping out.

Comment: The important distinction is between a jq program and its substrate (the data).

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is helping me understand the core issue of difference in data types I was working with.